# When do we merge the content of a closed beta site with an existing site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, data-dump, beta-phase, beta-sites

I was searching for closed beta sites and I found them.
These are the beta sites that were closed and their data dump of questions is downloadable on Area 51
[Open Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65426/open-science)
[Machine Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning)
[Game Theory](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory)
[Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence)
[Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence)
[Firearms](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164?page=4&phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top)
[Home Automation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55835/home-automation)
[Game of Go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go)
[Libraries & Information Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12432/libraries-information-science)

This one's data dump is not downloadable and it's not merged with an existing site (I think [the knowledge that went into the site is lost](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5498/142064))
[Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating)

This one's data dump is not downloadable but it's merged with an existing site
[Guitars](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6320/guitars)

But the content of the following sites is downloadable and their content is merged with an existing site:
[Astronomy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy)
[Theoretical Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics)

Now my questions are:

- how do we choose what to do after closing a beta site?
- How do we choose which of the above four actions is best for a
  closing beta site?
- When do we merge the content of a beta site with an existing site
  after closing it?

**Note:** I had asked this question on [Area 51 Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22193/142064) but they advised me to ask it here

Comment: Is the difference for that Relationship and dating proposal that it never entered public beta?

Comment: Well, the first thing to check is if there's a _healthy_ site that would welcome the closed beta's questions. For some of your closed but not merged examples such a site might exist today, but it might not have existed back when they were closed. Also, even if a healthy site exists, there's no guarantee that its community will agree to a merge.

Comment: @rene Open Science, machine learning, Artificial Intelligences, Home automation, Game of Go never entered public beta, too

Comment: Check the [site-salvage](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-salvage) tag on Meta Physics, for discussions relating to the Astronomy and Theoretical Physics merges.